# Search Header Row and Go To The Specific Column That's Found

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

So the following code grabs the header row and populates each field in a combobox.

I then want to select a field name from the combobox and go to that column in the datagridview, is that possible?

```
    Dim c As Integer
    For cn = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        c = c + cn
        'Debug.Print(cn)
        'Debug.Print(DataGridView1.Columns(cn).Name)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(cn).Name)
    Next cn
```

Comment: `dgv1.CurrentCell = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)`  (I'd populate the CBO from the DataTable)

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated! @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to check that the DGV has data and perhaps that there is a `CurrentRow`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, 
        e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' ToDo: check that the selectedIndex is valid vs dgv.Columns.Count

    If dgv1.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
        dgv1.CurrentCell = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Else
        dgv1.CurrentCell = dgv1.Rows(0).Cells(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah my first row will always have data in them. I'm going to looking into the schema link you posted yesterday, I need to treat all fields as text.